# Execute terraform command conditionally by OS type

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

I am running terraform 0.15. I am using local-exec to run a command. The command needs to run only when the workstation I deploy from is Windows. Needs to skip for non-Windows (mac, linux etc).

Is this something achievable? Appreciate any help.

Comment: You need to wrap the command with conditionals that are valid for all three shell interpreters (so probably use a common language with an installed interpreter) to verify the operating system.

Comment: What's the command that you need to run? It depends on the command, but in general I'd recommend doing this with a wrapper script around your call to terraform rather than baking it into the terraform itself.

Comment: @DanMonego PowerShell is the command. Sure, i like that idea for future updates. Here is a case where it's a minor update, so want to keep consistency.